Reduction from weighted graph to unit disks in $\mathbb{R}^2$
I was reading about unit disk problem. People converet given disk instance to an intersection graphs and then claim about hardness of graph problem on this clas of graph.
But can we do other way around? Like given a weighted graph we create unit disk instance from it. Where weight is distance between centers of intersecting disks.
If it is not possible, what are the reasons behind it? Is it possible to obtain such a disc instance specifically for any graph class?
